# spring integration dsl filter instead filter method annotation

Tags: java, filter, spring-integration, dsl

How can I switch from filter annotation method to Spring integration java DSL filter. how can I call filter method?

```
IntegrationFlows.from("removeSession")
                // remove chat session from user sessions map
                .handle("sessionLogService", "removeChatSession")
                // continue and remove user from ehcache only if user have no more opened sessions.
                .filter(/* what's going here? */)
                .get();
```

instead Filter annotation.

```
@Filter(inputChannel = "userGoOfflineFilter", outputChannel = "userGoOffline")
    public boolean notifyOnlyIfLastConnectionClosed(SecureUser secureUser) {
        ChatUser user = sessionUtils.getChatUser(secureUser.getId());
        if(user == null || user.getChatSessionIds() == null || user.getChatSessionIds().isEmpty())
            return true;
        LOGGER.debug(secureUser.getFirstName()+": Offline message not sent yet");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several overloaded `.filter()` methods on `IntegrationFlowDefinition`. Take a look at the javadocs, but

```
filter("expression");
```

takes a SpEL expression. It could be a bean reference, such as

```
.filter("@myFilter.notifyOnlyIfLastConnectionClosed('payload')")
```

or you can use a `GenericSelector`...

```
.filter(SecureUser.class, u -> u == null || u.getChatSessionIds() == null || u.getChatSessionIds().isEmpty())
```

(java 8 lambda) or

```
.filter(new GenericSelector<SecureUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(SecureUser u) {
                        return u == null || u.getChatSessionIds() == null || u.getChatSessionIds().isEmpty();
                    }
                })
```

(java 6/7).

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much this .filter("@myFilter.notifyOnlyIfLastConnectionClosed('payload')") work perfect and I like it. :)