# Is there a way to write a filter in spring-integration using java annotation?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to convert xml configuration in spring-integration, and I encountered a filter that goes like:

```
<
  int:filter
  expression="someFilterExpression"
  input-channel="inputChannel"
  output-channel="outputChannel"
  discard-channel="discardChannel"
/>
```

Is there a way to come up with a Java annotation equivalent for this? I've tried to use the @Filter annotation, but it didn't include the expression field in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for pointing me to the right direction. To elaborate further on what I did. I put in the spring integration dsl dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and used the IntegrationFlows to build the filter. I did it by:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow filter() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("someInputChannel")
        .filter(
            "someFilterExpression",
            e -> e.discardChannel("someDiscardChannel"))
        .channel("someOutputChannel")
        .get();
}
```

So, the above Java DSL is basically the same as:

```
<
  int:filter
  expression="someFilterExpression"
  input-channel="someInputChannel"
  output-channel="someOutputChannel"
  discard-channel="someDiscardChannel"
/>
```

Thank you very much again for your answer. :)

Comment: Note: if you upgrade to the latest Spring Integration, you don't need that extra `spring-integration-java-dsl` dependency: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. If you're using annotation, the whole reason for it would be because you have some complex logic that *can not* or *should not* be expressed in SpEL, so it gives you an opportunity to write some java code and let the framework know that this is a filter. 
There is also DSL and I think this post covers it pretty well - [spring integration dsl filter instead filter method annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371718/spring-integration-dsl-filter-instead-filter-method-annotation)